# Twitter User Timeline no longer working

Tags: twitter

As of June 11, the twitter timeline that worked with this code is no longer working:

`<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`<script src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/anthonyteacher.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I used this code to custom display a simple list of tweets on my website. I check the documentation regarding the new API code but could not figure out how to get my simple tweet list back. Any help?

Here is my full original code:

```
<body>
<div id="twitter">
<h1>Twitter Feed</h1>
<div id="twitter_m">
 <div id="twitter_container">
 <ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/anthonyteacher.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

I have also tried using OAuth to get it to work with no luck:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/plugins/twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "anthonyteacher";
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey = "key";
$consumersecret = "key";
$accesstoken = "key";
$accesstokensecret = "key";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

It returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up OAuth with twitter https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

or you can use this free service to get your tweets through javascript: http://getmytweets.co.uk/

Comment: I installed this github library (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) and configured it so I can use the Twitter API but it still didn't work. I'll check the site you mentioned.

Comment: I used my Get My Tweets and it seems to work well, though I haven't figured out how to style it yet.  I also retried using OAuth and still have had no luck. I edited my original post with the OAuth Script.

Comment: you style it using just your local CSS, by default it will return your tweets in a div with the class of 'tweet', so to style that you would just in your stylesheet do .tweet { color:#000; } .tweet a { color:#ff0000; } for instance

Comment: infact, for your site i would do this `.tweet {margin-top: 10px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size: 11px; }`

Comment: and i would also remove the div `twitter_m` completely.. then your feed will look awesome :)